# problem with css file

Tags: asp.net, css, themes

I'm having problem with themems.
I have app_themes folder in my application that have a mytheme folder.In that folder
I hvae placed a css file.
I have used this theme  thruoghout the application.
using the web config file....follwing is the code.

```
<System.web>

<pages theme="mytheme"></pages>

</System.web>
```

it's worikng fine..but problem is tht i dont want htis theme on a particular page.

for this i have used

`Enablingtheme ="false"` in pagedirective.but  it is still appliying to the page.

Please suggest something to me...

thanx in  advance.. 
...

Comment: Where is the css ? I don't think your question is about css..

Comment: It is about css. ASP.NET just wraps it around with so called 'themes'.

Comment: I don't think the problem is from a CSS file but more about some ASP.NET coding.
I said that because the question was just tagged css..

Answer (score 2):

Well `EnablingTheme` is not the correct property name. it's

```
EnableTheming="false"
```

I'd check that you haven't a typo in there first.

Comment: ya i have used the  same ..but not working
EnableTheming="false"